# Copy Constructor not working in List initialization of array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class, copy-constructor

Whenever i make my own copy constructor for a class the list initialization stops working and i get the error : class "Batman" has no suitable copy constructor

```
class Batman{
    private:
        dhaga real_name;
        long double moneys;
    public:
        static int cnt;
        dhaga batamobile;
        auto counter() -> void{
            cnt++;
        }
        Batman(dhaga name):real_name(name){
            counter();
        }
        Batman(){
            counter();
        }
        Batman(Batman&){
            counter();
        }
};
```

**initialization:**

```
Batman bruce[2] = {Batman(), Batman("bruce wayne")};
                       ^         ^
                      error     error
```

whenever i remove my copy constructor it starts working again

**Solved :**

problem was in list initialization the copy constructor needs to be constant and since i had a custom copy constructor it overridden the const one

making my CC const solves the problem

```
        Batman(const Batman&){
            counter();
        }
```

Comment: You didn't define `Batman::cnt` static variable. Try `int Batman::cnt = 0;` out side of your class.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani i had that somewhere, nvm solved the problem

Comment: Copy constructors should take in a const reference, i.e. `Batman::Batman(const Batman& other)`. The issue here is that you are trying to copy temporary objects, which is not possible, as they don't bind to `Batman&`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann, BTW, `T::T(T&);` is a valid copy constructor: https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor

Comment: @GhasemRamezani While technially valid and usable in some cases, it is a **bad practice** to define such copy constructor because **(1)** user of the code do not expect that a copy modify the original object and **(2)** if one follows the guideline to use `const` whenever possible, then he will soon have problem copying objects.